# PIL unidentified Image error occuring when running code

Tags: python, runtime-error, python-imaging-library

I am following a course on webscraping, trying to run the following code which is meant to search bing images for a term and save all images into a folder scrapedimages

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image

search = input("Enter the term you want to search:")
params = {"q": search}
r = requests.get("https://www.bing.com/images/search", params=params)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
links = soup.findAll('a', {'class':'thumb'})

for item in links:
    img_obj = requests.get(item.attrs["href"])
    print("Getting image from:",img_obj)
    title = item.attrs['href'].split('/')[-1]
    Img = Image.open(BytesIO(img_obj.content))
    Img.save("./scrapedimages/"+title, Img.format)
```

However, I get the following error when my search term is "pizza"

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/dilan-sheth/PycharmProjects/Udemy/WebScrapery/images.py", line 45, in <module>
       Img = Image.open(BytesIO(img_obj.content))
    File "/home/dilan-sheth/PycharmProjects/Udemy/WebScrapery/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2930, in open
    raise UnidentifiedImageError(
PIL.UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x7f9654ada7c0>
```

Any reason this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

The `UnidentifiedImageError` occurs when you use `PIL.Image` to access an image of 0KBs or a file which is not Image. 
So most probably what you are trying to access through `Image.open` is most probably either an image of 0KBs or a `requests.get(item.attrs["href"]).content` is not returning a valid image file. Later seems to be the case in your code.
Hope it helped!